# Serializing a jquery post to look like a normal form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to integrate a jquery .post with a php script that expects the field names to be the $_POST array keys like $_POST['field_name']. If I write out key value pairs like this

example 1:

```
$.post("http://localhost/post_handler", {
    'foo' : 'bar' //<- key value pair
    },
    function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    },
    'json'
);
```

it posts perfectly, meaning $_POST['foo'] = 'bar'. Unfortunately there are hundreds of fields and I can't write them out. If I try

example 2:

```
var post =  $("form").serialize();
$.post("http://localhost/post_handler", {
    post
    },
    function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    },
    'json'
);
```

the the back end gets something like:

```
  $_POST['post'] = 'field1=1&field2=2&field3=3'
```

and I would have to split the fields on the back end.

For this project I don't have access to the back and can't control what the server does with the post. I need the back end to handle this like a normal form submission. Again, I have hundreds of fields, so I don't want to have to write it out like like example 1.

I could possibly do a loop, but I figured that there had to be a built in way to do this.

Comment: In example 2, the post var is inside a object ({}), pass it directly: $.post(url, post, function, 'json');

Comment: `var post =  $("form").serializeArray();`

Comment: @rogeriolino. Thanks. That was simple. If you want to make it an answer I'll check it right away.

Comment: @AuntJamaima ok, I've added an anwser. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented

> In example 2, the post var is inside a object ({}), pass it directly: $.post(url, post, function, 'json');

```js
var post =  $("form").serialize();
$.post("http://localhost/post_handler", post,
    function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    },
    'json'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="i1" value="v1">
  <input type="text" name="i2" value="v2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is almost correct, you just need to pass the `post` variable directly to the second parameter of `$.post`, ie. not wrapped in `{}`. Try this:

```
var post = $("form").serialize();
$.post("http://localhost/post_handler", post, function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Thank you. It really was a really simple mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

remove the curly braces around post variable should give you the results you expect...  The curly braces would only surround the data section of the post() statement IF you were breaking out the name/value pairs as a JS object (i.e. ...{element:value, element2:value2}.

$.serialize() returns a string not an object (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)- so simply pass it without making it an object...

```
var post =  $("form").serialize();
$.post("http://localhost/post_handler", post ,
    function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    },
    'json'
);
```